# jquery flot, varying size and color for each point

Tags: jquery, flot

Can we change the following properties of the points in a jquery flot plot:

**the size of dots** : I am basically trying to plot a three dimensional graph. First two dimensions are the x and y values and the third dimension value will be reflected in the size of the points. Larger the value, larger the point.

**the color of the dots:** Again, am trying to display a property other than the x and y values. larger the value, darker the point.

**[EDIT]**: I am trying to control these properties for points individually and not for the whole plot.

Comment: Did you read the documenation (http://flot.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/API.txt)?  Both of these options are available (under "Customizing the data series", fill and radius)

Comment: @Mark Umm, I read that. Plz correct me if I am getting it wrong but those options shadowSize and colors will take effect on all the points in the plot. I am trying to vary shadowSize and colors for individual points. Like a dot representing a country with higher population will have a bigger dot, something on those lines.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I understand you now.  The only way I can see doing this is by passing a callback function to the point symbol option:

```
function someFunc(ctx, x, y, radius, shadow) 
{
  someFunc.calls++;
   if (someFunc.calls % 2 == 0)
   {
    ctx.arc(x, y, radius * 4, 0, shadow ? Math.PI : Math.PI * 2, false);
   }
   else
   {
     ctx.arc(x, y, radius, 0, shadow ? Math.PI : Math.PI * 2, false);
   }
}
someFunc.calls = 0;

var options = {
  series: {
    lines: { show: true },
    points: { show: true, symbol: someFunc}
  }
};

somePlot = $.plot($("#placeholder"), [ d1 ], options);
```

In the above I am adjusting the radius size for every other point:

[image]

[EXAMPLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/larsenmtl/nUaxD/1/)

Comment: Thanks. This will do the job. The parameter `someFunc.calls` will keep track of the index of the point being plotted and is the same as the index of the `data[]` array which was passed to the plot function. The population value will be present in a separate array `pop_arr[]` with its index in sync with that of the "data" array. The radius will vary according to `pop_arr[someFunc.calls]`. Perfect.