# Use several symbols on a serie FlotJS

Tags: javascript, flot

I'm using FlotJS library and I'd like to display some points on a serie with several symbol types.
I'd like having lines displayed and several selected points but not all.
Is there any way to do this ?

EDIT :

I've just found [jquery flot, varying size and color for each point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8926513/jquery-flot-varying-size-and-color-for-each-point) who helped me understanding how it works but, I'd like keep

```
grid : {hoverable : true}
```

And it creates a display bug cause of modulo, is there a way to override that ?
The associated [JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/nUaxD/164/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To draw the highlights, flot is still calling the `someFunc` function and `someFunc.calls` is still incrementing and controling how the hightlights are drawn.  So, after the `$.plot` I'd just "turn if off":

```
someFunc.calls = 0;     
somePlot = $.plot($("#placeholder"), [ d1 ], options);
someFunc.calls = false;
```

Where `someFunc` is:

```
function someFunc(ctx, x, y, radius, shadow) 
{
    if (someFunc.calls === false) {
        // we are highlighting, draw it normal
        ctx.arc(x, y, radius, 0, shadow ? Math.PI : Math.PI * 2, false);
    } else {
       // intial draw, do fancy points...
       someFunc.calls++;
       if (someFunc.calls % 2 == 0)
       {
            ctx.arc(x, y, radius, 0, shadow ? Math.PI : Math.PI * 2, false);
       }
       else
       {
           ctx.arc(x, y, 0, 0, shadow ? Math.PI : Math.PI * 2, false);
       }
    }
 }
```

Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nUaxD/165/).